# PubSub + Reliable message delivery to unreliably present subscribers

Tags: rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, mule, unreliable-connection, reliable-message-delivery

I need to build a system that uses a Publish/Subscribe bus (e.g. Mule, ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ), but the literature all implies that subscriber applications are reliably available to receive messages from topics to which they subscribe as soon as the Pub/Sub bus is able to deliver the message.

I have a system where some of the applications will be reliably connected to the Publish/Subscribe bus, but other applications will not be active or connected to the bus all the time.

The obvious solution is to have some sort of "presence" protocol between the unreliable application and the Publish/Subscribe bus so that "present" applications get their messages delivered immediately, and "not present" applications have their messages queued up in a persistent buffer of some kind, and as soon as they complete the "presence handshake", the queued messages are delivered to the newly present application.

Are there any Publish/Subscribe buses which have this kind of feature built in, or are there any open-source add-ons which do this? Can you point me to any URLs which describe this?

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this behaviour quite easily with any AMQP-compliant broker (such as RabbitMQ).

Choose the correct exchange type for your usage model. You'll want to use a `direct` exchange if you're always sending to absolutely named destinations, something like `chat.messages`.

If you want to do pattern-based routing, you'll want to use `topic` exchange. Then you can route based on patterns such a `chat.messages.*`.

Routing is described in more detail in the [RabbitMQ Tutorials](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html).

To create the kind of persistent subscription that you mention, have each subscriber create a queue that is private to that subscriber. The queue is then bound to the relevant routing keys on your chosen exchange.

Since each subscriber has its own queue, messages will be consumed by the subscriber when active and stored when subscriber is inactive or disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned your language of choice, but in Java you can accomplish this with [JMS](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/basics.html) using *[durable subscribers](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/advanced.html#1024758)*.  Any implementation of JMS ([there are many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service#Provider_implementations), including the aforementioned RabbitMQ) will support this feature.